# jQuery mobile appyling on every web page

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am learning jQuery mobile. I have 3 webpages : Home, About & Contact Us.
What i am doing is :

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
```

I just want to apply jQuery mobile features on home page not on other two.
I have written this code only on the home page. But on viewing this page in the browser the other two pages are also using jQuery mobile features.
I don't know why it is happening. 
It would be great if my problem gets resolved.

Comment: Can you define what kind of jQuery mobile features you want to exclude for the other pages? It seems to not make sense in using non-jQuery mobile features when all your webpages are related (Home, About, Contact Us).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery mobile framework is designed to be "single page", here's their description from [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)

> jQuery Mobile is designed to work with simple page linking conventions. Essentially, you can link pages and assets as you normally would, and jQuery Mobile will automatically handle page requests in a **single-page model**, using Ajax when possible. When Ajax isn't possible (such as a non-same-domain url, or if specified using certain attributes on the link), a normal http request is used instead.

Consider adjusting the config options upon auto-initialization: https://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i 100% understand your question, but a good practice is to stylize each page as so. Then add "!important" to each line. I know people might say that's bad practice, but jQuery mobile is kinda weird like that, and it works for me

```
#home{
    background-color: red !important;

}
#page2{
} etc etc
```

Comment: maybe post your website or a jsfiddle or something

Comment: Thank you Sir for showing concern into my problem. I am still working on that project. And yes my problem is now solved. What i wanted earlier was that i wanted to use jQuery Mobile feature on only home page. But by default it was applying on other pages also. But on correcting my code : <a data-ajax = "false" href = "#"></a> i got my solution.